# Is there a database of every scientist with their scientific interests?

Tags: citations, computer-science, job-search, data, databases

Is there an open database of every scientist with their scientific interests? For example, I want to find a list of all scientists with their contact details based in the UK, whose scientific interests include, say, databases. I have an idea and I would like to approach some of them with it.

Edit: such database does exist, I used it almost 10 years ago for different reasons, cannot remember its website anymore :(

Comment: If you really mean every scientist regardless of country or field,  then the answer is no. If you mean every scientist in a particular subfield in a particular country, then possibly.

Comment: Not every. Half of them, even 1% would be enough.

Comment: If you have no idea who does research in the topic then your ideas need to be researched better before researchers will be likely to respond in the first place.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I fully agree in the described case. Note, though, that the problem could indeed occur legitimately, such as when doing "meta-research" (research about the processes and state of research).

Comment: relatively good coverage:
https://orcid.org/orcid-search/search

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this database exists, but you might try searching the literature archives. Databases like Web of Science might help you.

Comment: I too am not familiar with such a database.  If it existed, I might be loathe to appear in it.  I'm sure the very well known professors get contacted with "isn't this a great idea that would interest you" often enough already.  The more this happens, the less likely people will even look at such inquiries.

Answer (score 3):

Such databases exist. They are called publication catalogues or a scientific libraries.

You are not going to get a more accurate and uniformly complete picture of what researchers are working on other than by looking at their research output. There is no detailed, standardized, and complete classification of research topics, either, and if there were one, it would quickly be moot<sup>1</sup>, as research topics are merged and new ones are created all the time. Moreover, knowing that a given researcher works on databases is not going to help you much: They might do research about the performance optimization of DB engines, or about domain-specific DB access languages, or about conveying the contents of DBs to blind users, or about the legal ramifications of possibly slanderous statements in crowd-sourced DBs ... you get the idea.

After a basic pre-selection of publications by keywords, you will have to look at each researcher and their profile individually to determine whether their research interests are actually related to your idea.

<sup>1</sup>: I am looking at you, ACM paper classification.

Comment: I don't think publication catalogs necessarily provide contact information, but one should be able to "join" that data with public info (web searches) to get the right contact info.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answers that suggest publucation databases as the way to go. Additionally, you can use the [advanced search of ORCiD](https://orcid.org/orcid-search/search) and search for keywords but the results are only as good as the keywords which have to be entered by the researchers themselves.